# GZIPInputStream fails to read concatenated .gz files bug resolved?

Tags: java, gzip, gzipinputstream

Does anyone know if this bug
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=2192186

has been resolved yet? It is causing issues on our side in data collection from archive or archives. Looks like this is a very old issue:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4691425

If it is resolved, please let me know JVM version that contains the fix.

Comment: If you have a chance to replace implementation you could try to use workaround at bug id 2192186.  The best way to test if its fixed or not use latest jvm 1.6.37 or 1.7.9

Comment: The workaround would be to simply repeat GZIPInputStream on the input until you have no more input.  A concatenated gzip stream is just that — multiple gzip streams concatenated.  So if GZIPInputStream can read one, then it can read the next one as well.

Comment: Apache Commons Compress has [GzipCompressorInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/compressors/gzip/GzipCompressorInputStream.html) which seems to address this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I check it again and released that [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=2192186) is already fixed (check its status and resolution fields). Here is related [commit](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2010-May/002035.html). Make sure that you are using latest Java version.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering over a year, late but I thought the answer would help others because I too had this problem and it took me a while to find which version.

The answer is the GZIPInputStream concatenation bug fix was released in Java 6u21-rev-b08 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/overview-156328.html

However, it looks like the official Java 6u21 release was based on build 7 so that fix probably isn't in the official release until Java 6u22 even though it does not appear in the release notes.

I would think that this means it is in all versions of Java 7 since 6u22 came out a year before Java 7 was released.  It is definitely in the latest Java 7 release.