# Android: uncompress concatenated gzip-compressed files

Tags: java, android, gzip

`gzip` is [documented](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip) to support concatenation of compressed files:

```
$ echo hello >hhh
$ echo world >www
$ cat hhh www
hello
world
$ echo hello | gzip >hhhh
$ echo world | gzip >wwww
$ cat hhhh wwww | gunzip
hello
world
```

I can create a concatenated file with `GZIPOutputStream`, but unfortunately `GZIPInputStream` reads only the first portion of data (`gunzip` run from the command line reads all.)

I'm seeing this on both Android 4.1.2 and 4.4.2.

***How do I read the whole file from Java?***

UPDATE:
An example demonstrating the bug (the host version):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;


class GZTest {
    static void append(File f, String s) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
            //FileOutputStream gzos = fos;
            GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
            gzos.write(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            gzos.close(); // TODO: do it finally{}
            fos.close(); // TODO: do it finally{}
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    static String readAll(File f) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            //FileInputStream gzis = fis;
            GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            int len = gzis.read(buf);
            gzis.close(); // TODO: do it finally{}
            fis.close(); // TODO: do it finally{}
            return new String(Arrays.copyOf(buf, len), "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("~~~");
        File f = new File("x.y");
        f.delete();
        GZTest.append(f, "Hello, ");
        GZTest.append(f, "world!\n");
        System.out.println(GZTest.readAll(f));
    }
}
```

Running it:

```
$ javac A.java
$ java A
~~~
Hello, 
$ gunzip <x.y
Hello, world!
```

UPDATE2
It looks like this is the bug JDK-2192186, reported to be fixed on 2010-08-03. Nevertheless, the bug is here now.

Comment: Have u tried creating a second 'GZIPInputStream' after the first one finished?

Comment: By the way, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749891/gzipinputstream-fails-to-read-concatenated-gz-files-bug-resolved

Comment: Yeah... BTW, I'm seeing the same bug on the host with `java version "1.8.0_31"` The bug report offers a workaround, but the code is terrible. Did Oracle publish the code with the fix applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have just tried the solution from  [truncated output from GZIPInputStream on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661312/truncated-output-from-gzipinputstream-on-android): it works.
To clone the branch with the fix, https://github.com/ymnk/jzlib/tree/concatenated_gzip_streams , use:

```
git clone https://github.com/ymnk/jzlib.git
git checkout concatenated_gzip_streams
```

and then copy the directory *src/main/java* (you cannot copy just one file) to your project and replace the import:

```
//import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import com.jcraft.jzlib.GZIPInputStream;
```

**It works on Android!**

If you want **to remove unneeded files,** you **will** need:
*Adler32.java   Deflate.java        GZIPInputStream.java  Inflate.java              InfTree.java     Tree.java
Checksum.java  GZIPException.java  InfBlocks.java        InflaterInputStream.java  JZlib.java       ZStream.java
CRC32.java     GZIPHeader.java     InfCodes.java         Inflater.java             StaticTree.java*
and **will not** need: 
*Deflater.java  DeflaterOutputStream.java  GZIPOutputStream.java  ZInputStream.java  ZOutputStream.java  ZStreamException.java*

Looks like removing 6 unused files (24K) while leaving 17 files (198K) is not worth the result.

Answer (score 0):

As to the host java, the right way to read is:

```
static String readAll(File f) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        //FileInputStream gzis = fis;
        GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
        final int SIZE=4096;
        byte[] buf = new byte[SIZE];
        int len=0, read=0;
        do {
            read = gzis.read(buf, len, SIZE-len);
            if (read < 0) {
                break;
            }
            len += read;
        } while (len<SIZE);
        gzis.close(); // TODO: do it finally{}
        return new String(Arrays.copyOf(buf, len), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

(this *readAll()* is to be used in place of *readAll()* in the question)

**This code does not work on Android!!!**

On Android, this still gives

```
D/~~~     (30098): Hello,
```

while the command line gunzip says

```
# cat /data/data/com.example.gzctest2/files/x.y | gunzip
Hello, world!
```